# map() with async vs promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

If I have an array of elements and I want to do parallel operations on them.
I would use `promise.all()`. 

I knew `promise.all()` accepts array of promises. Correct me if I am wrong, I don't think so.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), it clearly says.

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled or when the iterable contains no promises or when the iterable contains promises that have been fulfilled and non-promises that have been returned. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects, or with the error caught by the first argument if that argument has caught an error inside it using try/catch/throw blocks.

So, yes we can pass simple functions to `promise.all()`, and it resolves if they return and rejects if they throw an error.
Now look at the below code.

```
const promises = todayAssignedJobs.map(async todayAssigned => {
  const [leaderboard, created] = await Leaderboard.findOrCreate({...});

  if (!created) {
    const rating = (todayAssigned.rating + leaderboard.rating * leaderboard.jobs_completed) / (leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1);
    const commission = todayAssigned.commission + leaderboard.commission;
    const jobsCompleted = leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1;

    await Leaderboard.update({
      rating,
      commission,
      jobs_completed: jobsCompleted,
      updated_by: 'system',
    }, {
      where: {
        id: leaderboard.id,
      },
    });
  }

  await AssignedJob.update({
    is_leaderboard_generated: true,
  }, {
    where: {
      id: todayAssigned.id,
    },
  });
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Here, I have a doubt.
We are iterating on each element of the  array and doing operation on them asyncrhonously. They don't return anything explicitly. 
*So, I think map is doing parallel operations here too.* 
Why shuold then use `promise.all()` here?

Comment: *Why shuold then use promise.all() here?* As opposed to..? Were you thinking of a `for` loop instead?

Comment: Not at all, if map() does asynchronously. Why do we need both? Does map() waits for first asyncrhonous operation to finish here? What does promise.all() does in this case?

Comment: _"They don't return anything explicitly"_  `async` functions by definition return a `Promise`

Comment: Do you need to perform any actions **after** all your mapped async functions complete? If so, that's what you need `Promise.all()` for. If not, then you can do without it and your mapped functions will do what they gotta do without interrupting the code outside

Comment: "if map() does asynchronously" map doesn't do anything asynchronously.

Comment: @Kaiido We are doing async operation on each element. It might wait for that to finish(correct me here, please)  but operation is asynchronou here.

Comment: _"It might wait for that to finish"_  if by _"it"_ you mean `.map()`, then no, _it_ won't wait for anything

Comment: @Phil If it won't  wait, then it is doing things parallel. right?

Comment: Correct but there's better information below 

Comment: Nope, map is all synchronous. It will declare your  Promises synchronously. Maybe easier to grasp with a setTimeout? `[1,2,3,4].map( () => setTimeout( doSomething, 3000) )` will return the result of `setTimeout()` (the timeout id) synchronously, even though doSomething will only get called in 3s

Comment: @Phil A very informative piece of info I was missing here is this  `async fun() { await some(); await another(); }` what willl be returned here?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari a `Promise` that resolves (with no value) when `some()` and `another()` have completed

Comment: @Phil Got it, `fun()` will return a `Promise`. It will be resolved when all promises insde it resolves and will be rejected if one of them rejects?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari correct. It's the equivalent of `return some().then(() => another()).then(() => {})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.map()` is not promise-aware.  So, when you pass it an `async` callback like you are, it does not pay any attention to that returned promise.  So, it just runs the loop one after another, not waiting for any of the returning promises.  Thus, all the asynchronous operations started in the `.map()` loop will be in-flight at the same time.

If that's what you want and you want to collect all the returned promises so you can later see when they are all done with `Promise.all()`, then this pattern works well:

```
Promise.all(someArray.map(callbackThatReturnsAPromiseHere))
```

And, this is a common design pattern for it.  In fact, the Bluebird promise library has a special function that combined these two called `Promise.map()`.  It also offered another nice feature that let you control how many concurrent async operations could run at once (because it's `map()` operation is promise-aware).

It sounds like you're trying to figure out if you should only use `.map()` and not use `Promise.all()`.  If you do that, you will run your asynchronous operations in parallel, but you will not have any idea when they are all done or any ability to collect all the results.  You would use `Promise.all()` on the array of returned promises to know when they are all done and/or to collect their resolved results.

FYI, `.map()` is JUST a plain loop.  It doesn't have any special asynchronous features or any special run-in-parallel features.  You can do the same thing with a `for` loop if you want.  It does NOT pause for your `async` callback to wait for it to be done so a side effect of running it is that you launch a bunch of parallel asynchronous operations.

Comment: I am flabbergasted. At least I was right, `map` will fire them parallel. _It won't  wait for their returned value_ this line is awesome. I wasn't aware. That's why I should do `promise.all()` to mak sure all promises all fullfilled.  :)

Comment: So, basically now promise.all() will watch their returned promises, if they got resolved or not, right?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari - Yes, the entire purpose of `Promise.all()` is to watch an array of promises and tell you when either the first one rejects (and report the reject reason to you) or when they all complete (and report an array of resolved values) and `.map()` does not do that for you.  `.map()` will collect the array of promises for you just like it collects any return value from the callback and run the initial loop, but that's the end of what it does.

Answer (score 4):

You only need `Promise.all` if you want to do something when all operations are complete. For example:

```
const promises = todayAssignedJobs.map(async todayAssigned => {
  // lots of async stuff
});

await Promise.all(promises);

// now, all Promises have resolved
// alert the user that the leaderboard is completely updated
```

If you don't need anything to occur once you've determined that all Promises have completed, then there's no point to the `Promise.all` - you may as well just create the Promises in a loop and leave them as-is. In that case, since you wouldn't be using the resulting array of Promises, it would be more appropriate to use `forEach` (which is the array method to use for side-effects).

There's one issue, though - you aren't handling errors, but errors *should* be handled, otherwise they'll give warnings or exit the Node process:

```
const processJob = async (todayAssigned) => {
  const [leaderboard, created] = await Leaderboard.findOrCreate({...});

  if (!created) {
    // ...

// ...
todayAssignedJobs.forEach(async todayAssigned => {
  try {
    await processJob(todayAssigned);
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `Promise.all` here is to be able to await all the promises before continuing.

If you added a console.log immediately before the `await Promise.all(promises);` it would run synchronously before any promises have resolved, whereas a console.log immediately after that line will only appear after ***all*** the promises have resolved.